# Can PHP do a fairly trivial inheritance thing?

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I have the following code:

```
abstract class AbstractParent {
 function __construct($param) { print_r($param); }
 public static function test() { return new self(1234); }
}

class SpecificClass extends AbstractParent {}
```

When I invoke `SpecificClass::test()`, I am getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class AbstractParent
```

So what I basically want is just to let `AbstractParent`'s `test()` instantiate class where this `test()` was called from (so, in my example, instantiate `SpecificClass`).

Comment: I've been seeing people complain a lot about late static binding lately and I'm curious: What other languages commonly used for web development *do* support late static binding? Python? Ruby? Perl? Java?

Comment: all of them, afair. I used Ruby extensively over past couple of years.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance of static members in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532754/inheritance-of-static-members-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

Prior version 5.3 Only with the following work around:

```
abstract class AbstractParent {
 function __construct($param) { print_r($param); }
 abstract public static function test();
 private static function test2($classname) { return new $classname(1234); }
}

class SpecificClass extends AbstractParent {
 public static function test() {return self::test2(__CLASS__);}
}
```

Comment: You don't have to have the two static methods named differently.  You can call them "test" in both classes and have SpecificClass::test return parent::test.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in PHP 5.3, which is still in alpha. What you're looking for is called Late-Static-Binding. You want the parent class to refer to the child class in a static method. You can't do it yet, but it's coming...

Edit: You can find more info here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php