# Static in php, why it use one cache for both class

Tags: php, oop

I create parent class for my models, it look like this

```
class Model {

   protected static $cache = [];

   public static function load($id)
   {
       return static::$cache[$id];
   }

   public static function findById($id)
   {
       $model = static::find($id);

       static::$cache[$id] = model;

       return model;
   }

   ...
}
```

And i have two child class, examples

```
class A extend Model {}
class B extend Model {}
```

then, i write

```
A::findById(1);
B::findById(1);

$a = A::load(1);
$b = B::load(1);
```

I think type of class $b is class B, but not, it is class A, because function "load" use static cache and load result from function A::findById(1). Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance of static members in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532754/inheritance-of-static-members-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By accessing static class properties as `static::$cache` you tell the interpreter to use the `$cache` property of the class used to call the method and not the one of the class where the method is defined.

In plain English, when you call `A::findById()` you expect that `findById()` uses the property `$cache` of `A` and not the one of `Model`. The same for `A::load()` and similar for `B::findById()` and `B::load()`.

The question now is: do the `A` and `B` classes declare a static property `$cache` on their own? Because if they do not declare this property, the `static::` in front of `$cache` in the function `A::findById()` cannot find `A::$cache` and uses `Model::$cache` instead. The same for `B::findById()`.

The easy solution to your problem is to declare the `protected static $cache` property in all classes that extend `Model`.

*The correct solution is to not use static properties and methods. Static properties and methods are not OOP. They are procedural programming (and thinking) disguised as OOP code. Code that is difficult to understand and test.*

Comment: Thank you, i understood!

Answer (score 2):

static properties are inherited, if you want to have them separately, redefine them

```
class A extend Model { static $cache; }
class B extend Model { static $cache; }
```

---

also what you are trying to do is bad OOP practice.

this is how you can do it *proper* way

```
class CacheFactory
{
    static public function createModelCache($model)
    {
        static $instances = [];
        if (!isset($instances[$model])) {
            $instances[$model] = new Cache($model);
        }
        return $instances[$model];
    }
}

class Cache
{
    protected $name;

    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
}

abstract class Model
{
    abstract protected $name;

    /**
     * @type Cache
     */
    protected $cache;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cache = CacheFactory::createModelCache($this->name);
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        if (($data = $this->cache->get($id)) !== null) {
            return $data;
        }
        $data = ...;
        $this->cache->put($id, $data);
    }
}

class A extends Model
{
    protected $name = "modelA";
}


class B extends Model
{
    protected $name = "modelB";
}
```

**this just an example** and you can change few bits like

- you can move `CacheFactory::createModelCache` to `Cache`
- you can use `get_class` instead using `abstract protected $name`
- you can just create static array instead `Cache` class

but thing is - you just don't use `static` everywhere, this is not how you code in OOP

from my example you can see **the only thing what is `static`** is an array with `Cache` objects and factory method. this is only thing you need to store globally.

Comment: Thank you, i already create like in your answers, but not understand, why php not create protected static $cache = []; in each classes with empty value

Comment: @ConorHolt why should PHP create `$cache` in the derived classes? Static properties are not class members, they are global variables (possible with limited visibility) with funky names.

Comment: @ConorHolt static properties are inherited