# How to retrieve a static property of the subclass in a static method in the super class

Tags: php, oop, static, php-7, static-methods

I have a situation similar to the following code:

```
class ParentClass
{

    public static $property = 'parentValue';

    public static function doSomethingWithProperty() {

        echo 'Method From Parent Class:' . self::$property . "\n";

    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass 
{

    public static $property = 'childValue';

}


echo "Directly: " . ChildClass::$property . "\n";
ChildClass::doSomethingWithProperty();
```

Running this from the cli I get the output:

```
Directly: childValue
Method From Parent Class: parentValue
```

Is there a way to retrieve the static property defined in a subclass from a static method defined in the parent class?

Comment: Static values are not overridden in heritage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532754/inheritance-of-static-members-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance of static members in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532754/inheritance-of-static-members-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `self` keyword always reference same class.

To allow overriding of static property/method you have to use `static` keyword. Your method should look like this

```
public static function doSomethingWithProperty()
{
    echo 'Method From Parent Class:' . static::$property . "\n";
}
```